# How to generate a first order Gauss-Markov process in Python

Tags: filters, python, noise, scipy

I would like to synthesize a first order Gauss-Markov process from a white Gaussian noise.

I know from signal processing theory that it could be realized using a noise shaping filter designed properly (see [Gauss-Markov process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_process)).

First order Gauss-Markov processes can be described from two key parameters: $\sigma$, which is the standard deviation of the process, and the time constant $\beta$.

The shaping filter should have a transfer function equal to the one in this figure:

[image]

Here it is my code:

```
import scipy.signal as dsp
import numpy as np

Nsamples = 2000
fs = 100

time = np.arange(Nsamples) / fs

rng = np.random.default_rng()
gaussianNoise = rng.standard_normal(size=time.shape)

whiteGaussianNoise = (gaussianNoise - np.mean(gaussianNoise)) / np.std(gaussianNoise)
print('\n\n\nWGN MEAN: ', np.mean(wgn))
print('WGN STD: ', np.std(wgn))


beta = 0.01
sigma = 0.1
b = np.array([np.sqrt(2 * beta * sigma**2)])
a = np.array([1, beta])

gaussMarkovNoise = dsp.lfilter(b, a, whiteGaussianNoise)
```

Unfortunately, something is wrong because the gaussMarkovNoise should have an autocorrelation with an exponential decay (see http above); while filtered in this way, it still has a spike in the origin as a white noise sequence. What am I missing?

Comment: I think, judging from the linked wikipedia article, that this is the same as an [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process).  If that's the case, first generate completely independent and uncorrelated (white) random numbers.  Then pass this white-guassian noise through a simple first-order low-pass filter.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that your values for $\beta$ and $\sigma$ are way too small.

If I try

$$ \beta = 0.01$$
$$\sigma = 0.1$$

then do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
acf = plt.acorr(gaussMarkovNoise, maxlags = 1000)
```

then I get

[image: OP's values for beta and sigma]

However, if I do

$$ \beta = 1$$
$$\sigma = 1$$

then I get

[image: Larger beta and sigma values used (both 1)]

which is much more like what you expect.